# Few keywords waits for 15 seconds by default instead of configured polling time

Tags: robotframework

**Scenario**: In a web page,click button and verify the popup window is displayed. In popup window, select the value in drop down.

```
Click Element     ${Add-Button}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds     20s     1s    Element Should Be Visible      ${City_drpdwn}
```

After clicking Add button, page loading icon is displayed.After 5-7 seconds, popup is displayed.
But the above script, waits for 15 seconds by default. It is not polling for every 1 second as mentioned in script.So, script unnecessarily waits for more time, even after the expected element is displayed.

Instead of 'Element Should be Visible' in above script,
tried with other keywords also. But the same issue occurs.It waits for 15 seconds by default.

Other Keywords are

- Element Should Not be Visible
- Page Should Contain Element
- Page Should Not Contain Element
- Wait Until Element Is Visible
- Wait Until Element Is Not Visible

Any suggestions/inputs would be helpful.

Comment: There is no default value for waiting in `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`. And since other keywords also "wait" for 15 seconds, obviously these 15 secondes come from something else. Are you sure you haven't 15 seconds sleep time in `Click Element`?

Comment: @Psytho I haven't given any sleep time.

Comment: What's in the logs?

Comment: Test gets passed. But time for executing this keyword is displayed as 00:00:15.144.

Comment: @Psytho U can check by executing in any website with the below script:

Wait Until Keyword Succeeds     20s     1s    Page Should Contain Element      <${element}>

Comment: I have not seen what you report with any of the keywords you mention. The problem must be somewhere in your own keywords, or there must be more to the problem than you're describing.